# How to get a list of the IDs is present in a table or not in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, roles and role_Family.

Role table has role_oid which is a primary key, role_name and then role_family_oid which is a foreign key.
Role_family table has role_family_oid which is a primary key and role_family_name. Note that there is a one-to-many relationship between the tables, i.e. one Role_family may have zero, one or more than one associated Roles.

Now I have a list of role and role family combinations, I need to check whether that particular combination is present in DB or not.

I need an output table like

| Role | Role Family | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Role 1 | RoleF 1 | Exist |
| Role 2 | RoleF 2 | Absent |

Comment: @Abra meaning one role family is connected to many roles.

Comment: A [mcve] should include _both_ sample table data _and_ the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
r.role_name AS Role,
rf.role_family_name AS Role_Family,
CASE WHEN r.role_oid IS NOT NULL THEN 'Exist'
ELSE 'Absent'
END AS Status
FROM role r
LEFT JOIN role_family rf
ON r.role_family_oid = rf.role_family_oid
WHERE (r.role_name, r.role_family_oid) IN (
        ('Role 1', (SELECT role_family_oid FROM role_family WHERE role_family_name = 'RoleF 1')),
        ('Role 2', (SELECT role_family_oid FROM role_family WHERE role_family_name = 'RoleF 2'))
    );
```

Comment: A *good* answer should explain what the code does and why it answers the question.